# Memory Leak in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem related to Memory Leak. In my app I have to read 2MB data from a Video file, and the method related to same always called when the Activity's onCreate method called then the same statement which allocated 2MB byte array in the code, returns OutofMemory Exception frequently after 10 to 15 attempts because heap memory exceeds. The code is explained below (it is the part of my whole code):

```
//Reading DRM video from sdcard
                File file = new File("/sdcard/TvAnyTime/watch/"+IDValue+".mp4");
                   try {
                          is = new FileInputStream(file);
                   } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                          e2.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   //reading 2^21 bytes
                   fileData = new byte[2097152];
                   int read = 0;
                   while(read != fileData.length) {
                      try {
                    read += is.read(fileData, read, fileData.length - read);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   }

                   //The finalHashPattern is then xored across the video file 2^10 times
                   for(int i=0;i<2097152;i+=2048)
                   {
                    byte[] res = new byte[2048];
                    bytesafterXor = new byte[2048];

                    for(int j=0;j<2048;j++)
                    {

                        res[j] = fileData[i+j];
                        bytesafterXor[j] = (byte)(res[j]^finalhash[j]);
                        finaldatafile[i+j] = bytesafterXor[j];
                    }

                    finalHashafterXor.add(bytesafterXor);

                   }
```

The statement `fileData = new byte[2097152];` is responsible for the OutOfMemory Exception because it is allocated every time when onCreate is called. Can we prevent the same by allocating each time a large memory? can we read it in chunks of data? Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_embedded) and read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html)?

Comment: Actually youtube is not accessible from my office.

Comment: Try https:// instead of http:// ;) If they've blocked the website via URL, then this should work. If they've blocked it via IP, then sorry my friend. Do the videos in the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html) website work?

Comment: *byte[] res = new byte[2048];* and *bytesafterXor = new byte[2048];* should *definitely* be moved outside the loop! - And *read += is.read(...)* is a bad idea, too, as *read()* will return -1 when hitting the end of the file.

Comment: what I should use instead of read += is read();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since my edit to Kingamajick's answer "mysteriously" disappeared while waiting for peer review, here is how to do file (or streams in general) chunked reading right:

```
fileData = new byte[2048];
try {

  int c = 0;
  while( (c = is.read(fileData)) >= 0 ) {

    // Process all bytes from fileData[0] through fileData[c-1], e.g.:   
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      // do something with fileData[i]
      // ...
    }
  }

} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that for files, the buffer (`fileData` above) will most likely always be completely filled by the read operation until there are not enough bytes left to read in the file. When reading from, for instance, network streams this is usually not the case as data is not always instantly available and when it becomes available it is likely just as much data as arrived in the last network packet. However, the above approach works for all streams.

Edit:

From your comment I take that you do not want to process the whole file but only the first 2mb. In this case you can modify the above approach a bit, like:

```
fileData = new byte[2048];

int leftToRead = 2048*1024; // Total amount of bytes you want to read.

try {

  int c = 0;

  // How many bytes may we read at once?
  int maxRead = Math.min( fileData.length, leftToRead );

  while( (leftToRead > 0) && (c = is.read(fileData, 0, maxRead)) >= 0 ) {

    // Process all bytes from fileData[0] through fileData[c-1], e.g.:   
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      // do something with fileData[i]
      // ...
    }

    // We read c bytes, so we may have some bytes left:
    leftToRead -= c;

    // How many bytes may we read at once?
    maxRead = Math.min( fileData.length, leftToRead );

  }

  // Optionally:
  if ( leftToRead > 0 ) {
    System.out.println("Premature end of file.");
  }

} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When processing the file byte-by-byte, as you do in your code excerpt, you can basically freely choose the size of the `fileData` buffer. A smaller buffer does not provide any real benefit, because it may cause more read operations on the underlying file system. Something in the range from 1kb to 64kb is usually a good size.

Comment: Thanks Hanno for your response but You just only read 2048 bits everytime which is not required and it is not continuously increased to 2097152 therefore I can't use this code because I have to read 2MB data from a file.

Comment: Please see my edit. You do not want to read the whole file, right?

Comment: Yes Hanno and Thank you very much for responding just like this..I think this is the correct approach and definitely it will work...Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered processing the input inside the loop where your reading the bytes in, rather than reading all of the bytes

```
fileData = new byte[2048];
int read = 0;
while(read != fileData.length) {
    try {
        read += is.read(fileData, read, fileData.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
            // Processing here
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may put **fileData** as a static pointer an then in case **onCreate** alloc memory only once, when **fileData==NULL**;

Comment: Second solution is free memory onStop and alloc onStart, not onCreate. See android app lifecycle: http://pds11.egloos.com/pds/200812/01/63/c0043363_49336ea62d4c6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude this critical file processing from Java code to Native code. 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/files/JNIExample.pdf